# Excel VBA autofill and source is range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have define a name for my data, so when I put a new data in my cell, it will be also included on my autofill code

name of cell is ident

```
=OFFSET(DataSource!$A:$A,1,0,COUNTA(DataSource!$A:$A)-1,1)
```

This is my code for autofill on combo box

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
UserForm1.Label1 = Date
For Each blah In [ident]
    UserForm1.ComboBox4.AddItem blah
Next blah

End Sub
```

Im getting an error, variable not define and highlighted "blah"

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` in your module (it will be the first line if it's there).  If so, then that's good, but you will need to add `Dim blah as Variant` to your sub

Answer (score 1):

Chris Neilsen is probably right.  You mostly likely have `Option Explicit` at the top of the userform  module which requires `blah` to be decalred.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim blah As Variant
    UserForm1.Label1 = Date
    For Each blah In [ident]
        UserForm1.ComboBox4.AddItem blah
    Next blah

End Sub
```

Here are two other ways that you can define the range:

`For Each blah In [OFFSET(DataSource!$A:$A,1,0,COUNTA(DataSource!$A:$A)-1,1)]`

`For Each blah In Range("OFFSET(DataSource!$A:$A,1,0,COUNTA(DataSource!$A:$A)-1,1)")`